# How to use Yolo as DLL after building Yolo as C++ DLL-file yolo_cpp_dll.dll

Tags: c++, object-detection, darknet, yolov4

I have trained and built Darknet yolov4 with my custom dataset and made it work as darknet.exe file on windows with GPU. I run my exe with my custom parameters like

```
"`darknet.exe detector demo ball_config/yolo.data ball_config/yolov4-custom_best.cfg`
```

I try to run the same model as dll from a C++ code. I have built `yolo_cpp_dll.sln` and generated `yolo_cpp_dll.dll` under "\build\darknet\x64" . But i do not know how to call this dll. Also i am not sure how can i call this dll with my custom weights and cfg files to detect the object.

Can anybody have any experience with this?

I followed the entire repository of Alexey [https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Did you miss [this section of the README](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll-and-so-libraries)?

Answer (score 0):

Note you are using an abandoned repo, and unsupported API.

The new Darknet/YOLO repo is this one:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#table-of-contents

And the recommended C++ API is DarkHelp:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/darkhelp/api/API.html

As user Botje commented above, if you want to use the old C++ API, the old readme file does have a section about it:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet/blob/master/README_previous.md#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll-and-so-libraries

But personally, I recommend that people switch to the new  DarkHelp API instead, since it is both maintained and properly documented.